# Control attackers from modifying resources in a URL

Tags: java, security

How do I keep attackers from modifying resources in a URL? If I need to create a list of legitimate resource names that a user is allowed to specify, and only allow the user to select from the list, how do I do this in case of URL API?

I have `URL url = new URL(urlName);`

Comment: Suggest posting on http://security.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Are you trying to prevent people from breaking into your server and changing the responses that it sends to clients?  Or are you trying to prevent people from requesting URLs that aren't in the list you said are allowed?

Answer (score 0):

You might consider declaring a constant.

Static Final String URL_CHOICE1_EXAMPLE = http://www.actual.URL.forExample;

Then let them pick from the name of the string "URL_CHOICE1_EXAMPLE" and not the actual URL value.

Not sure what you're UI is but if you can use a picklist, combobox, listbox, etc. that would also do the trick. Ideally use both.  The Final prevents the value from being overridden.

Hope that helps.